# How to join 3 table with this condition?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 3 tables: `product`, `customer` and `transaction`.

Product:

```
id_product    price
    1         1000
    2         2000
```

Customer:

```
id_customer    name
    1          Tom
    2          Jack
```

Transaction:

```
id_transaction    id_product     id_customer    qty    date
    1                 1              1           10    2013-02-21
    2                 2              1           50    2013-02-21
    3                 1              2           15    2013-02-21
```

I want to achieve this result:

```
id_customer      name      total_transaction      purchase_qty      subtotal
    1            Tom             2                     60            110000
    2            Jack            1                     15             15000
```

How I can get that result using a query in MySQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT  t.id_customer, c.name, 
        COUNT(t.id_customer) AS total_transaction, 
        SUM(t.qty) as purchase_qty
FROM transaction t
INNER JOIN customer c
ON t.id_customer = c.id_customer
GROUP BY t.id_customer,c.name
```

Comment: @AdvaitAmin overall, i understand how to make a subtotal, but i just forget to put group by(actually i never use that). So, using group by solve my problem.

Comment: @fenzkurol if the answer is acceptable, when it will fulfill all requirements of user who ask question.

Comment: @AdvaitAmin Yup, I got it. Btw, thanks u for your response..:)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT cs.id_customer, cs.name, COUNT(tr.transaction) AS total_transaction, SUM(tr.qty) as purchase_qty, SUM(tr.qty*pr.prize)
FROM customer AS cs
LEFT JOIN transaction AS tr ON tr.id_customer = cs.id_customer
LEFT JOIN product AS pr ON pr.id_product = tr.id_product
GROUP BY cs.id_customer
```

I suppose you are a total beginner, so I did this for you. Next time, if you have ANY own ideas, give to us, so we don't have to write the whole query for you. Show some effort.

Comment: My mistake is i don't ever use group by and now, i using my own query (using subquery not JOIN) and i put group by and it give the result that i want. Btw, thank's for your advise.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT c.id_customer, c.name, count(t.id_transaction) AS total_transaction
FORM Customer c INNER JOIN Transaction T
 ON C.id_customer = T.id_customer
GROUP BY c.id_customer
```

Comment: This query will not produce the all required result.

Answer (score -1):

You need a `group by` statement since you want to aggregate results for a given customer :

```
SELECT id_customer, name, count(id_transaction) AS total_transaction
FORM Customer, Transaction
WHERE Transaction.id_customer = Customer.id_customer
GROUP BY id_customer
```

This does not solve your whole problem, but you've got the idea.

Comment: i think when you want to join 2 or more table you must using subquery or join like from customer as a, transaction as b. How can you just write where transaction.id_customer = customer.id_customer?

Comment: If you don't use `as` then you can use your tables' names as identifiers